# Chrome extension onUpdated wait until page is loaded

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to stackoverflow :), I tried to search the question here but unabe to find exact problem.

I need to add a script to google search page which is working fine in first attempt.

For example, if I go to chrome and search anything on google.com then script works fine.

But on search page, i.e. on this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Ezy.png) if I try to search any new result then it shows last searched result html.

My code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabid, info, tab) {
    if (info.status == "complete") {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file: "code.js"});
    }
});
```

And my code.js

```
$(function () {
   var htm = $("#rcnt #center_col").html();
   console.log(htm);
});
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Subsequent searches are loaded via Async requests. The tab/page is not refreshed. Suggest you check the page url or title for changes.